# What kind of app is this?

Tags: android

I installed yesterday this app http://www.appbrain.com/app/mini-info/com.dynotes.miniinfo from android market on my phone.

But I've never seen such apps before. It doesn't look like a widget, it looks like custom dialog.

So, does anybody know, what technique has the author of this app used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the left screen isn't a widget, it's most likely a regular Activity but with a theme that looks something like this:

```
<style name="Theme.FloatingMenu" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

And this theme is applied to the Activity in the manifest file like this:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.MyActivity"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.FloatingMenu" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Without having tried the app I would say that the one to the left is a dialog, and the ones to the right are regular widgets.

Answer (score 1):

Description
A simple & hassle free way for device info. **Widgets, toggle bar, and lots more!**

https://market.android.com/details?id=com.dynotes.miniinfo&feature=search_result

Comment: but widgets are on the second screenshot. The first one is no widget, i'm pretty sure. But maybe i'm wrong

Comment: I think it is widget. The widget is pressed. But maybe i'm wrong ))